# Displaying 2 Employees' First and Last Name joined through the employee's ID

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a **Transaction table (named G7)** that has fields of

```
1. ID
2. Module ID
3. Employer ID
4. Employee ID (From) - **refers to Employee ID Table** -
5. Employee ID (To) - **refers to Employee ID Table** -
6. Transaction Date
```

And the **Employee ID** (**named I9**) table that has fields of

```
1. Employee ID
2. Employee First Name
3. Employee Last Name
4. Employee Email Address
```

In the output SQL statement report, I need to have the transaction report (based on (G7)

```
1. Transaction Date
2. Employee First Name (From)
3. Employee Last Name (From)
4. Employee First Name (To)
5. Employee Last Name (To)
```

It's annoying that I still can't get the SQL statement to work.  Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT Transaction.TransactionDate, 
  A.FirstName, 
  A.LastName,
  B.FirstName,
  B.LastName
FROM Transaction
JOIN Employee AS A ON Transaction.From = A.EmployeeID
JOIN Employee AS B ON Transaction.To = B.EmployeeID
```

If you try to get data with a different meaning of the same table, make sure to create a difference between them by defining an alias with "AS". Besides you have to define the join in the proper way. I guess to find the combination of both was your problem.